# Can we use wildcards with NETSH HTTP ADD URLACL in Windows 7 / 2008r2?

Tags: windows, iis, netsh, iis-express

i'm using IIS7 express and therefore need to unblock port 80 if I wish to hit the website locally and on the default http port. To do this, i use ..

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://my.custom.locahost.domain.com:80/ user=mydomain\myusername
```

is it possible to say something like

```
netsh http add urlacl url=*:80/ user=*
```

so basically, anything going to port 80, by anyone, is allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx which shows this:

netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

My understanding is that it will listening to anything at port 80 and if you want it linked to a specific address, you'd actually have to unbind it. That's what I have to do if I want to run IIS and Apache on the same box with both listening to port 80.

For the user, domain\domain users should be a valid domain group which includes everyone.

Comment: I found that I had to use `*` instead of `+`. My binding looks like `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1421:*"/>`. Why does `+` work for you?

Comment: @binki Both are valid with slightly different purposes. See [Routing Incoming Requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/routing-incoming-requests) for further information.

Answer (score 28):

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=Everyone
```

Note that the valid value for `user` actually depends on your system language (`Everyone` for English, `Jeder` for German).

Comment: +1 For the localization information

Comment: "Tout le monde" for French

Comment: I think, `Jeder` (GER) and `Everyone` (ENG) and `Ĉiuj` (ESO) and `Каждый` (RUS) are ridiculous... But it is MS-approach, and who am I to judge them...

Comment: I really thought this was a joke until the moment I saw it working.

Comment: System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
System.Security.Principal.NTAccount acct = sid.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)) as System.Security.Principal.NTAccount ;
Console.WriteLine(acct.ToString());

...as posted by user "LucVK-T" on social.msdn

Answer (score 16):

Basing on @jgillich answer, I propose to do the following:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ sddl=D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-1-0)
```

`sddl` argument will be virtually the same as `user`, but you don't need to think of a localized group name. So, it's more universal.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use S-1-2-0 to only use local users?

Comment: in our configuration we need domain user support, S-1-2-0 would not work, but if someone can confirm one form is valid for local users and the other for domain users that would be excellent information.

Comment: @DenisV do you have any documentation what "D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-1-0)" means?

Comment: @Peter maybe this can be an answer: https://itconnect.uw.edu/wares/msinf/other-help/understanding-sddl-syntax/

Comment: @DenisV thanks that explains the first part but not `S-1-1-0` and `S-1-2-0` but it will do!

Comment: @Peter, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649(v=vs.85).aspx) you have more information

Comment: This does not seem to work in Windows 10, I get a `Missing closing ')' in expression-.` error.

Comment: @HåkonK.Olafsen it does work. Proof: https://snag.gy/8KqaIU.jpg

Comment: Not here: https://snag.gy/Vke3PJ.jpg @DenisV

Comment: @HåkonK.Olafsen don't use powershell for this command. Use classic windows shell (cmd.exe).

Answer (score 1):

My best guess was to set exactly the same url you add to the listener and do:

```
 netsh http add urlacl url="[exact same value]" user=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
```