# change default port of IIS and let another process to listen on port 80 (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an installation of Windows Server 2008 running IIS 6 with a website listening on port 8080, even though I have moved the website to listen on 8080, port 80 is still kept in use by IIS (for truth by the kernel process : System - ProcId : 4).

I want to let another process listen on port 80 without uninstalling or disabling IIS, I want to keep IIS listening on port 8080 and another service on port 80, is there a way to do it?

I saw another similar thread [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/142062/how-to-get-a-service-to-listen-on-port-80-on-windows-server-2003) on serverfault but the solution (`using httpcfg.exe delete iplisten -i 0.0.0.0:80` ) can work only in 2003 because in 2008 the utility httpcfg.exe doesn't exist and it seems that it cannot be installed ...

Does anyone have a solution to get rid of the kernel listening on port 80 in Windows Server 2008 with IIS running?

Comment: Have you restarted the IIS Services ? If not you could try this !

Answer (score 1):

Aleroot, go to c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv and then run the command "appcmd list site" ; this should give you a good starting point and list all the sites with their configs

> c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list site
>   SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,https/*:443:,net.tcp/808:*,net
>   .pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,state:Stopped)
>
> SITE "Exodus" (id:2,bindings:http/*:8080:,state:Started)

Answer (score 0):

Check IIS configuration to ensure that there isn't a website called "Default Website" running and listening on port 80.

If you stopped that website, you might still have to delete it, or put is on another port to free up port 80.

Comment: I've already changed the binding listening port of IIS bet still something listening on 80.

Comment: If you open a command prompt, and run 'netstat -o', you can identify the open port, and correlate it to a PID. You can then use Task Manager to identify the PID that is controlling this port. You might be surprised to find that it is not IIS.